# Tomb Raider Anniversary Achievements/Trophies

Tags: achievements, tomb-raider-anniversary

After completing the game I found some achievements requiring to complete Peru, Greece and the other worlds without dying. Can I unlock them replaying all the levels or do I have to start a new game/save file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomb Raider Anniversary contains no missable achievements. This means all achievements can be obtained by replaying a certain level. This includes the no death achievements, the time trial achievements and the relic collection achievements.